# How to sort integer column in csv file in java

Tags: java, sorting, csv, arraylist, comparison

I want to sort integers from smallest to largest, but my output shows
1,
10,
100,
2,
20,
3,
30,...

I need to sort them like 1,2,3,4,5,6.....10. Please see my code below. I assume I need to use integers and not strings. I can't find how to change the code.

```
public class sortcolumn {
private static final String COLUMN_SEPARATOR = ",";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String csv = "C:\\Users\\c0leese\\Desktop\\Top app\\August2016\\aPaidApp_2016-08-16.csv";
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(csv);
    List<List<String>> lines = readCsv(inputStream);

    // Create a comparator that sorts primarily by column 0,
    // and if these values are equal, by column 2
    Comparator<List<String>> comparator = createComparator(0, 2);
    Collections.sort(lines, comparator);

    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\c0leese\\Desktop\\Top app\\August2016\\test.csv");
    String header = "Symbol, Exchange, Minimum, Average, Maximum, Total";
    writeCsv(header, lines, outputStream);        
}

private static List<List<String>> readCsv(
    InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    // Skip header
    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (true)
    {
        line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(line.split(COLUMN_SEPARATOR));
        lines.add(list);
    }
    return lines;
}

private static void writeCsv(
    String header, List<List<String>> lines, OutputStream outputStream) 
    throws IOException
{
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    writer.write(header+"\n");
    for (List<String> list : lines)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            writer.write(list.get(i));
            if (i < list.size() - 1)
            {
                writer.write(COLUMN_SEPARATOR);
            }
        }
        writer.write("\n");
    }
    writer.close();

}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<List<T>> 
    createComparator(int... indices)
{
    return createComparator(sortcolumn.<T>naturalOrder(), indices);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T>
    naturalOrder()
{
    return new Comparator<T>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(T t0, T t1)
        {
            return t0.compareTo(t1);
        }
    };
}

private static <T> Comparator<List<T>> createComparator(
    final Comparator<? super T> delegate, final int... indices)
{
    return new Comparator<List<T>>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<T> list0, List<T> list1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
            {
                T element0 = list0.get(indices[i]);
                T element1 = list1.get(indices[i]);
                int n = delegate.compare(element0, element1);
                if (n != 0)
                {
                    return n;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    };
 }

}
```

Comment: Consider posting an [MCVE]. The code can not be run as is, because the the cvs file is missing. For demonstrating the problem consider initializing `List<List<String>> lines` with string values. It will also make the code minimal.

Comment: Hint: your implementation of a CSV reader is absolutely deficient. Sure, it will work if you put down your own little example csv, but  it will fail you as soon as you try to process "real" CSV, generated from "real data". Long story short: CSV parsing is **harder** to get right than most people think. Thus: don't reinvent the wheel, use one of the many existing 3rd party libraries that do it for you. Plus: class names start UpperCase!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are creating the comparator to sort using `createComparator` which takes an array of indices (which translate to column numbers). It gives no indication of the type of each of column and, therefore, how to sort them. You would need to pass in something that indicates the data type.

However your code overcomplicates things by creating comparators that can be created natively with methods in `Comparator`.

For example

```
Comparator<List<String>> sorter = Comparator
    .comparing(row -> row.get(0))
    .thenComparingInt(row -> Integer.parse(row.get(2));
```

Would do pretty much exactly what your code does without all the comparator creation functions.